# Can I take off completely erase Ubuntu and reinstall Windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have looked just about everywhere, and I can't find an answer. I absolutely hate Ubuntu. It's messing everything up on my computer. I want to completely take off everything and reinstall windows. Although, stupid Ubuntu won't let me open EasyBCD because everytime I do, it says an error occured while loading the archive. Someone please help. I don't care what happens. Just no virus'. I do not have a disk with Windows. Thank you!

Comment: Just install windows and quit complaining about Ubuntu ;)

Comment: If you do not have a disk for windows how do you expect to install it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recovery partition on your hard drive then you can install Windows once again (restoring the factory settings). You can just delete the Ubuntu partition(s) in the process.  If you don't have a recovery partition you'll need a Windows install disk. Either you have such a disk, which you don't or you'll have to buy a new one. Ubuntu is not preventing you from installing any other new Operating System on your computer.

B.T.W.: EasyBCD is Windows software and it will not run on Ubuntu. Ubuntu is not Windows.

Comment: Thank you. Can we get in touch, say by email for further help. I'm not so tech savvy and need quite a bit of help. Thank you. email me at davidfloroiu@aol.com

Comment: Okay. I do not have a CD for windows 7. I have got to the page where to select my OS and then go and delete my partition, it does not show windows. I have gotten to the conclusion that from there, It does not have a windows partition. Is there a way for me to be able to get it not on CD mode. Torrent of some sort?

Comment: Windows is a commercial product so you'll have to buy a CD or you'll have to resort to illegal ways to obtain it but that's no suitable infomation for this site and I'll not recommend it either.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I think I know how to fix it now. Thank you once again for your help. My sincerest apologies for taking up your time. Cheers!

Comment: No problem at all. You're welcome.

Comment: @DavidFloroiu If you still have questions please post it here and we'll see what and how we can do something about it. If you're satisfied with my answer above then please click on the grey checkmark in the left margin next to my answer, so it turns green.